# Hyper-V: How to prevent automatic creation of vEthernet adapters?

Tags: docker, hyper-v, network-adapter, docker-for-windows

I installed Hyper-V on my Windows 10 machine to do some experiments with Docker. This caused a virtual ethernet adapter (called "vEthernet") to be set up automatically.

When this adapter was created, my Wi-Fi connection got disabled. (I assume that this is because of corporate security regulations.)

So I went ahead in disabling the vEthernet and re-enabling Wi-Fi. This allowed me to surf in the internet again.

---

After the next reboot, a second vEthernet adapter was set up. And the whole thing started again. Now I had two adaptors. And went ahead in disabling the new vEthernet and re-enabling Wi-Fi.

---

A few reboots later, my "Network Connections" look like this now:
[image: The Windows "Network Connections" with 13 vEthernet]

---

So my questions are:

1. What is actually the trigger that sets up new vEthernet adapters and connections?
2. How do I prevent the setup of new vEthernet adapters (if there are existings ones that might or might not be disabled)?

Comment: The "vEthernet (Default Switch)" is default you can't do anything. But those numbered interface may be from different docker containers or images.

Comment: What version?  There's a thread on TechNet that says updating to 1903 resolves this for some cases.

Comment: @essjae: Good to know. I'm still at 1803, so I'll try to get my laptop to update

Comment: @eesjae: The update to 1903 did not bring any help. The vEthernet switches keep being created. Do you happen to know of anything else that may help me?